# Checking if a record exists in a ms access database

Tags: vb.net

How to implement a code that will check if a data entered in textbox exists in ms access database and if it doesn't a msgbox is displayed and if it does, the button continues with the execution. I already have the code to read data from ms access and automatically fill relevant textboxes with data from ms access database

```
    'TO READ DATA FROM THE DATABASE TO THE TEXTBOXES
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    dataFile = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\IEBC ELECTIONS\Database11.accdb"
    Dim DD As String = "Select * from BY_ELECTIONS where REFERENCE=@RFR"
    Dim RFR = TextBox17.Text
    
    myConnection.ConnectionString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.Open()
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(DD, myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RFR", TextBox17.Text)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            TextBox11.Text += reader("COUNTY").ToString()
            TextBox9.Text += reader("TYPE_OF_ELECTION").ToString()
            TextBox12.Text += reader("CONSTITUENCY").ToString()
            TextBox13.Text += reader("WARD").ToString()
            TextBox14.Text += reader("DATE_OF_ELECTION").ToString()
            TextBox15.Text += reader("SEAT_CONTESTED").ToString()
            Dim MPS As String = reader("MP_TRAITS").ToString()
            Dim SENS As String = reader("SENATOR_TRAITS").ToString()
            Dim GOVS As String = reader("GOVERNOR_TRAITS").ToString()
            Dim MCAS As String = reader("MCA_TRAITS").ToString()

            TextBox4.Text = MCAS & GOVS & SENS & MPS
        End While
    End Using
    myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Please note that the string concatenation operator in VB.NET is `&`, so those should be `&=`. Also, just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @jmcilhinney yea. An if statement that will check if record exist. If it doesn't, a message box pops up saying 'Record not found' else button continues with the execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do in your SQL command is return the count of `REFERENCE` values where the value matches your parameter.

Then you would call ExecuteScalar on the OleDbCommand to return the count.

You're not quite done because ExecuteScalar returns an Object. Since you want the count, which is a numeric value, you will need to explicitly convert it to an Integer.

Take a look at this function which does those things I outlined above. As a fail safe, it returns -1 if something went wrong getting the data from the database:

```vb
Private Function getReferenceCount() As Integer
    Dim count = -1
    Dim connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\IEBC ELECTIONS\Database11.accdb"
    Dim commandText = "SELECT COUNT(REFERENCE) FROM BY_ELECTIONS WHERE REFERENCE=@RFR"
    Try
        Using con = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(commandText, con)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RFR", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox17.Text

                con.Open()
                count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' do something meaningful here, not just a writeline
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return count
End Function
```

To use the function to display your MessageBox:

```vb
Dim referenceCount = getReferenceCount()
If (referenceCount = -1) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong getting the count.")
Else
    MessageBox.Show($"There are {referenceCount} record(s) with the reference.")
End If
```

Comment: thanks for taking your time to answer me. Where do i add the `Dim referenceCount = getReferenceCount()
If (referenceCount = -1) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong getting the count.")
Else
    MessageBox.Show($"There are {referenceCount} record(s) with the reference.")
End If`

Comment: i tried the if else statement but i am not getting any feedback out of it.

Comment: @kelvincheruiyot - I don't know where you would put it. Button click? Timer tick? It is all up to you as to where it would go.

Comment: I inserted it on button click but still did not get any feedback to confirm if the record exists or not

Comment: @kelvincheruiyot check your output window to see if an exception was thrown.

Comment: I know where the problem was i changed referenceCount = -1  to referenceCount = 0 and it worked. Thanks alot bro